# Qué significa en struts 1 si la palabra dentro de path tiene como prefijo un punto (.)?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Estoy estudiando a struts y todo iba bien hasta que me encontré con algo que no me cuadra en absoluto.

En el archivo de struts-config.xml, las acciones registradas tienen varios forwards, cada forwards tiene un name como identificador y un path, que entiendo que es hacia dónde redirigirá. Por ejemplo:

```xml
<action type... path...>
    <forward name="pagina_jsp" path="jsp/pagina.jsp" />
    <forward name="bienvenido" path="bienvenido.do" />
<action/>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ¿qué significa cuando en el path viene así?

```xml
<forward name="otra_pagina_jsp" path=".pagina" />
<forward name="data_usuario_jsp" path=".data" />
```

¿Por qué tienen un punto de prefijo? ¿A qué hace referencia ese path?

¿Dónde está configurado en struts que ".pagina" o ".data" sean unas rutas hacia un archivo jsp?

Answer (score 2):

Hay un archivo que se llama tiles-def.xml, ahí está la referencia a cada uno de las palabras que tienen un punto como prefijo. En dicho archivo se relaciona la palabra con una url en específico.